# Unity type registration issue after Upgrade to Prism and Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I just upgrade Xamarin Forms and Prism and now I have a bunch of errors in my app.xaml.cs file for all the Unity registrations.  Plus as Brian stated in the update notes, all the Unity namespaces are broken as well.  For the little snippet below, what should the new RegisterTypes method look like and what should 1 of the container type listings look like?

This snippet used to work:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<ISession, SQLiteSession>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, Configuration>();
        Container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationRestClient, AuthenticationRestClient>();
```

Now it looks like it needs to look like:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterType<ISession, SQLiteSession>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, Configuration>();
        Container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationRestClient, AuthenticationRestClient>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing IContainerRegistry with the Unity Container. They are separate things. IContainerRegistry is an IOC abstraction in Prism 7 meaning it is not tied to the Unity API. You do however still have access to the underlying container when you need it. Your original snippet would become like the following:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISession, SQLiteSession>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IConfiguration, Configuration>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IAuthenticationRestClient, AuthenticationRestClient>();

    // You can also access the Unity Container by doing:
    var unityContainer = containerRegistry.GetContainer();
}
```

You can see the full definition for the [IContainerRegistry](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Ioc/IContainerRegistry.cs) on GitHub.

Comment: containerRegistry.RegisterType<> is still not a valid statement.